# Grabbing random image from directory based on command input

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Very new to this, but I'm trying to make a command for a discord bot that interprets a user's input, and gets a corresponding image based on a number they input.

Example : "!randomimag 3"

Output: Posts image named '3' in directory

I'm just trying to figure out the specifics on splitting the string into characters and reading the number to know which image to grab from the directory

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
let target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
let chars = message.split();
let imageNumber = chars[12]; //grab the 1 digit number that starts on 12th character

let embededImage = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setImage("/images/%s", imageNumber) //get corresponding image from directory

message.channel.send({embededImage: embededImage}) //send it yo
}

module.exports.help = {
name: "randomimag"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string like so:

```js
var content = message.content; //define content as the message
var parts = content.split(" "); //split it apart at the spaces
var userImput = parts[1] // get the 2nd part of the message
//(or whatever the user imputs after the command)
```

Then, to get the image-finding part working, you could make a string with a variable inside:

```js
var imagePath = `whatever-your-file-path-here/${userImput}.png`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting a command like
`!randomimg 3`
You could do a simple split on the string

```
let arr = message.split(" ");
//Splitting message at spaces.
let num = arr[1];
// Num contains 3 now
```